# How to communicate with my raspberry pi without using ssh or http?

Tags: remote, communication

I have a raspberry pi at home that I want to control from the "outside" world (e.g. my office). The thing is that my home router is not visible to the outside world; it's within some kind of a "subnet" of my ISP.

One of the things I'd like to do is take photos with the pi and send it to myself. By setting up ssmtp I was able to send the photos by email. But how can I tell the pi when to take a photo (currently it takes a photo automatically, every half-hour or so)?

I thought of Teamspeak because, as far as I remember, it gives you something like a phone number that you can call and connect to the remote machine. But I'm not sure Teamspeak is really available for the pi. And even if it were I'm not sure if it would light on resources, since I have a rather old pi (from 2011/12).

Is there some other way, preferably low on resource usage that you think I could use?

Comment: Normal home internet service usually does not include the kind of accessibility you are talking about.  You can use a service such as *weaved* or *noip* (see the duplicate Q&A).

Comment: Weaved is dead. https://developer.weaved.com/portal/

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'll have a look at the solutions mentioned [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/access-over-Internet/README.md). What I'll try to do tomorrow is call my ISP and see if they can give me a public IP (like I had in the past). Thanks again for your time.